# How to escape a quote in Postgresql command?

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am working on a script that creates a Postgres user with a variable input from a source file. As the user 'root' I run the following script:

```
su - postgres <<'EOF'
. /var.src
psql
CREATE ROLE john;
ALTER USER john WITH PASSWORD '$JOHNPASSWORD';
ALTER ROLE john WITH LOGIN;
CREATE DATABASE john;
ALTER DATABASE john OWNER TO john;
\q
EOF
```

I'm creating a user john and a database john, however john's password is in the var.src.
Everywhere I look I get commands similar to this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER john WITH PASSWORD '$JOHNPASSWORD';"
```

Replacing the password with $JOHNPASSWORD requires an escape I assume. I have tried escaping the single quote with a backslash, double-quotes, etc. Nothing. I haven't been able to find how I can escape the single quote so that it can read the variable from var.src.

Maybe it has something to do with how I'm approaching this entirely?

Comment: Is your last command in script ?

Comment: Yes. I am currently exploring options for exporting but I'm not sure

Comment: I ran your script and your command in the terminal. It works! how exactly have you tried to execute them?

Comment: I run it from my home directory using ./myscript in /root/myscript.sh. The problem is in var.src the variable is JOHNPASSWORD=myc00lpassword. But Postgres processes the user with the password $JOHNPASSWORD not myc00lpassword.

It sets the variable as a string.

Comment: you don't need to say the exact password. remove it and use some fake one. are you using it with root?

Comment: Can you come in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44272/helpline)

Answer (score 0):

I found something that helped. I supplied the password alter command after the script broke out of the EOF. So here is what worked for me:

```
    su - postgres <<'EOF'
    . /var.src
    psql
    CREATE ROLE john;
    ALTER ROLE john WITH LOGIN;
    CREATE DATABASE john;
    ALTER DATABASE john OWNER TO john;
    \q
    EOF

    . /var.src
    sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER john WITH PASSWORD '$JOHNPASSWORD';"
```

This is because I called the variable file again after the EOF. I'm sure that has to do with my previous assumption of escaping the quote. But this works also.